# UITableViewCell is nil if it's not visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

In my app I'm using [`ELCTextfieldCell`](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/elctextfieldcell). The idea is to use the data entered by the user for some calculations. But there is the problem. I have about 14 cells and, of course, they can't all fit on a screen. So when I click `OK` the app is checking if all fiels are filled in:

```
BOOL complete = YES;
for (int i = 0; i < [cellTextArray count] - [self.numberOfBools intValue]; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *iPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    ELCTextfieldCell *theCell = (ELCTextfieldCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:iPath];
    if (!theCell.rightTextField.text)
        complete = NO;
}
```

This code works perfectly if all the cells are visible, but if some are out, then the `complete` becomes `NO`. The output of `theCell` in `gdb` is:

```
(gdb) po theCell
Can't print the description of a NIL object.
```

Can somebody push me in a right direction please? :)

All help will be appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT**

`self.numberOfBools` is just an `NSNumber` with total of bools in these rows. They are using `UISwitches`, not `UITextField` as the other cells, so I excluded them from the check.

Comment: that's just an NSNumber. There are some bools and I just added an `UISwitch` for them, so there is no text in these cells(text fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete needs to be calculated on the data that is backing the cells rather than on the cells themselves. Let me explain.

The cell is a visual representation of your data and when it is not in view the run-time will release it and that is why it is nil.

However **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** creates the cell from data right? (or it is normal to do so) so when the user updates the cell.rightTextField you should update data.rightTextField and then complete should be looking something akin to ... and this is pseudocode not compilable

```
complete = YES;
for (Data* data in myDataSet) {
    if (!data.rightTextField)
        complete = NO;
}
```

So, in summary cells represent data and they are not guaranteed to persist. You yourself can ensure the data is persisted; therefore test for completeness on the data and not on the cells.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Cells in `UITableView` are reusable, and they can be released when invisible to save resources. You have to store your data somewhere else than in cells.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Damo and anticyclope here. You should have updated the

```
theCell.rightTextField.text
```

into your datasource of your table in the first place.

Then you could make your calculation based on the datasource.
Let `textFieldArray` be the datasource of your table.

`NSMutableArray *textFieldArray;`

`myTableView.dataSource = textFieldArray;`

Then need to update the datasource when the textfield is updated.
Finally you can process the datasource.