# When I scroll down, my selected values disappear from my tableviewController and pass null value to service

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I think my question might be confusing, so let me try to explain it in detail.
Below image is my tableViewController.

[image]

Now, as you can see I have selected four different values. If I click on save button now it will work fine. However, when I scroll down, Then the selected values disappear.

Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this?

Please ask me if its still unclear to you.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530417/uitableviewcell-is-nil-if-its-not-visible/9530768#9530768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scroll, the table view tries to reuse cells to improve performance, instead of creating new ones all the time. I guess that in your case, you don't have some sort of model that will store the status of your views, and when you scroll up to the first 4 cells in your example, some of the "empty" cells are reused, making the values "dissapear" as you say. Try to store your data in an array or a model class, and then use this array/model to populate the cell views properly in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: thanks mate for help. you are absolutely right. Yes, the empty cells are reused and thats why this problem is occurring in my App.